# Xamarin.forms Button Isenable failed

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, disable

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and I'm designing a quiz game. I want to make the button to be disabled after the user clicks it to prevent the user from choosing it again. I tried to use Isenable but it's not working.
if I miss putting some code, please point it out.

```
XAML CODE
 <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="C11" Text="$1" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="100"  Clicked="C11_Clicked" />
            <Button x:Name="C12" Text="$1" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="100"  Clicked="C12_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
       

    </StackLayout>
```

```
C# code
 private void C11_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            C11.IsEnabled = false;

            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new C11());
 
        }
```

updated part

```
 private void continue_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    
        {
            MainPage m = new MainPage();
            m.C11btn.IsEnabled = false;
            Preferences.Set("ButtonEnableFlag", false);
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
           
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var enableValue = Preferences.Get("ButtonEnableFlag", true);
            MainPage m = new MainPage();
           
            m.C11btn.IsEnabled = enableValue;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, from the shared code, there is no problem to disable the button first time. But if navigating to the next page, when backing the button will not be disabled.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT may i ask how to permanently disabled the button?

Comment: Yes, you can. I have updated the answer, you could have a look when you have time. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> may i ask how to permanently disabled the button?

If you want to make the button disabled permanently, you need to save *a **custom status flag*** in device. Next time entering to this view, the button will be disabled by this ***custom status flag*** programmatically.

For example, we can use **[Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)** to sace the custom status flag and override `OnAppearing` method as follows:

```
public partial class PageThird : ContentPage
{
    public PageThird()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyButton.IsEnabled = false;
        Preferences.Set("ButtonEnableFlag", false);
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var enableValue = Preferences.Get("ButtonEnableFlag", true);
        MyButton.IsEnabled = enableValue;
    }
}
```

Here is the Xaml code of this page:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <Label Text="Welcome to PagePersonal!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Text="Disable" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Now the button will be disabled permanently.

[image]

If you want to disable the button in another page, you only need to set the ***custom status flag*** in another page. Later when you back to needed page, the button will be disabled.

The another page code:

```
public partial class PageSecond : ContentPage
{
    public PageSecond()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageThird());
    }

    private void Disable_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("ButtonEnableFlag", false);
    }

    private void Enable_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("ButtonEnableFlag", true);
    }
}
```

Then it will work, no code need to change in the needed page.

[image]

Comment: sorry, I did not make the question clear, I would like to make the button permanently disable using another page .cs file, is that still possible??? and I had try to code you provides, it was not working. Appreciate your answer.I have already updated my question above

Comment: @JUSTINCHUA Hi, it's possible. If you understand my shared code, that's sure.You could set the status flag on other pages, and it will work when you back to the needed page. I will update answer, you can have a look when you have time.

Comment: hello .I have tried the first sample you post, and I have tried it already. yes it's work. but in my case, i have several buttons on the same page, but I don't want to make it disable at the same time. and seems like it is not possible to have multiple Override class on one page.

Comment: @JUSTINCHUA Hi, could you expain what your needs once time? From the question , I only know you want to diable a button and later said that need to disable it from another page. You not explained the detailed information about scene in your question. There are many ways to disable the butto of another page, and my shared answer is one of them. You also could use MVVM to bind the `IsEnabled` property to achieve that, it will be used for multiple buttons in one page.